# Postgresql database documentation

Tags: postgresql, documentation-generation

I'm looking for a FREE tool which allows to generate documentation for the DB schema, tables, column, keys, indices as a PDF or HTML format like the "Toad Data Modeler" which is a commecial tool.

I'm using Postgresql 9.2.

Could you suggest me some documentation generator?

Thanks

nico

Comment: `COMMENT ON TABLE foo IS 'bar'`?

Comment: Hi Denis, I'm looking for a documentation generator that exports DB schema, tables, column, keys, indices as a PDF or HTML format. THANKS

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your question accordingly to make this explicit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've generally found [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.org/) ([git repo](https://github.com/schemaspy/schemaspy/blob/master/README.md#schema-spy----schemaspyorg)) useful for this purpose. It gets the job done with minimal pain and produces quite useful output. The cross-linked multi-page HTML output is particularly useful.

Comment: Seems that the [repo has moved to github](https://github.com/schemaspy/schemaspy/blob/master/README.md#schema-spy----schemaspyorg) and the website to [http://schemaspy.org/](http://schemaspy.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at Foliant project

> Foliant is an all-in-one single-source documentation authoring tool.
> It lets you produce standalone documents in pdf and docx, build static
> websites and upload pages to Confluence, all from single Markdown
> source.
>
> Foliant is a higher order tool, which means it uses other programs to
> do its job. For building pdf and docx, it can use Pandoc or md-to-pdf,
> for websites MkDocs, Aglio or Slate.
>
> Foliant preprocessors let you reuse parts of your documents, show and
> hide content with flags, render diagrams from text, and much more.
>
> Foliant is highly extensible, so if it lacks some functions or output
> formats you can always make a plugin for it or request one from our
> team.
>
> Logo made by Hand Drawn Goods from flaticon.com.
>
> Who Is It for?¶ You’ll love Foliant if you:
>
> need to ship documentation as pdf, docx, and websites want to use
> Markdown with consistent extension system instead of custom syntax for
> every new bit of functionality like reStructuredText’s extensibility
> and AsciiDoc’s flexibility, but would rather use Markdown want a tool
> that you can extend with custom plugins without dealing with something
> as over-engineered as Sphinx want to work with docs as code and make
> them a part of your CI pipeline have a lot of segregated repositories
> with sources of your documents and want to standardize the
> documentation approach.

https://foliant-docs.github.io/docs/tutorials/db/pgsql/